# I can't login into laravel app, it's only possible if dev tools on chrome and mozilla are open

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have an issue with my laravel application. Login works only if i open dev tools on the browser. Is it maybe linked to the fact that chrome and mozilla are caching a page, or maybe the csrf token is not walid?

This is a blade

```
<div class="login-page">

    <div class="form" >
        <p style="display:none;" class="message" @if($errors->has('email') || $errors->has('password')) {{ 'has-error'}} @endif>Logovanje nije uspjelo!</p>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <div>
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <div>
                    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="lozinka" name="password" required>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>
                    <input style="max-width: 10px;text-align: left" type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Zapamti Me
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Login
                    </button>

                    <a class="message" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        Zaboravili ste lozinku?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="message">Niste registrovani? <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Napravite nalog</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller is default laravel cotnroller, didn't change anything. In web routes i have Auth::login();

Comment: You need to include more code, or no one can help you. What have you tried, snapshots, code, etc

Comment: I dion't have anything specific, it's default laravel login configuration. And the strange thing is that it works when dev tools are open. Thi is a link https://www.treningplan.trcizdravo.com/

Comment: php artisan cache:clear php artisan view:clear php artisan config:clear and make sure you have the right permissions set for the bootstrap folder

Comment: @Indra i tried, still the same thing. I log in and it redirects me to the right page, but it doesn't show i'm loged in. But if i turn on developer tools and do a refresh it's fine. How come a difference i can't figure it out.

Comment: try in incognito mode in your browser. if so then it's your browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experience you're describing is typical of code which contain `console.log()` or any of the other `console` functionality.

The console object is only activated when the Dev Toolbar is opened. Prior to that, calling the `console` object will result in it being reported as `undefined`. After the toolbar has been opened, the console will exist (even if the toolbar is subsequently closed), so your console calls will then work.